# looking at various mod_rewrite solutions for iis 6

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis-6

I have inherited a iis system with predominately php-mysql sites. We are looking to put in a few sites (mod-x and wordpress) where we need mod_rewrite for our iis 6 on 2003 win server.
I am quite keen to choose a solution where we can might be able to just port over the standard install of the above systems to a lamp box without changing too much of the config, ie re-write the rewrite rules. So ideally I guess we need some kind of plugin that will read the .htaccess files and compatible with mod_rewrite syntax.

I just wondered if people can recommend any of he solutions out there and recount their experiences? I am currently looking into ModRewritePro from http://www.micronovae.com/ and ISAPI_Rewrite from http://www.isapirewrite.com/

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) is a great product with 99% Apache compatible syntax and friendly manager. I'm using it for already a couple of years and it's great so far.

Comment: thanks for the that! Just playing around with it now...all i got to figure out next is regular expressions :)

Answer (score 1):

Fastream IQProxy is a better solution with half the cost for windows platform

Answer (score 0):

[IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) does what you want, lots of WordPress admins use it.  Mostly compatible with .htaccess syntax.  IIRF is free.  Works with IIS6 or 7.